# ALTER command denied - MySQL

Tags: mysql

Any ideas why I keep getting this error?

```
alter table tastes
add constraint uniqueTaste
check (upper(taste) not in(select upper(taste) from taste));

insert into tastes values(1, 'Tasty');
```

If I try this instead it works:

```
alter table tastes
add constraint uniqueTaste
check (taste != 'Tasty');

insert into tastes values(1, 'Tasty');
```

This only happens when I try to use the first constraint.

Why is that?

Comment: Pretty sure mysql does not support a subquery in a check constraint

Comment: View the rules for check constraints here- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html

Comment: @P.Salmon and Raymond thank you very much.